# Hook up visual studio profiler to Azure Service Instance

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, azure, service, azure-worker-roles

i am not sure if this is the correct place to put of this question as this has nothing to do with coding but rather configuration. My apologies.

I want to hook up my visual studio 2012 profiler to a azure service WaWorkerHost.exe which is hosted on Windows Azure.

After much searching i found [Profiling Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-performance-testing-visual-studio-profiler/). But this shows only how to profile WaWorkerHost.exe which is currently running on localhost i.e. on Azure Simulator rather than on actual Cloud.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is something you're looking for, but you can enable profiling when you publish your cloud service through Visual Studio.

[image]

and here's a link which talks more about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh369930.aspx.